# is it possible to protect tensorflow training code

Tags: tensorflow, encryption, cython, nuitka

Now a days very high power shared GPUs are available for deep learning training at very cheap price. But protecting your training dataset and code is problem there because GPU owner can see your files. I know that it is impossible to completely prevent, reverse engineering of the code and data, but I want to make it very very hard. I am thinking to encrypt my datasets images and decrypt problematically before feeding to the model.But the problem is, anyone intelligent enough can see my decrypted data when i feed to the model.
What are the options to hide TensorFlow code and build c++ binary? I tried Nuitka, its not working with tensorflow. I searched that Cython will also not work. There is tf-encrypted but, it seems like that work with older version of tensorflow (1.x). Please suggest some clever way which works.

Comment: It seems like recent pip packages of tf-encrypted depend on TensorFlow 2.x and python 3.6-3.8. I'm using python 3.10 and running into import issues which is not a good sign if developers are already not keeping up.